# How to use Attributes for authentications on ASP.NET Webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, webforms

I have a Website which has several aspx pages that derives from a PageBase class. For example one of that is below:

```
public partial class Pages_Home_Default : PageBase
{
}
```

In some of these pages, I would like to prevent access UNLESS logged in. I can get whether client is logged in or not in my PageBase with a IsMember property.

I would like to use attibutes to achive that. For example:

```
[AuthenticationRequired(true)]
public partial class Pages_Home_Default : PageBaseList
{
}


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AuthenticationRequired : Attribute
{
    public AuthenticationRequired(bool isMemberRequired)
    {
        Value = isMemberRequired;
    }

    public bool Value { get; private set; }
}
```

and in the PageBase for example:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve the AuthenticationRequired attribue value and if not authenticated Redirect client to a login page if logged in, continue displaying the page
}
```

I also found this to get and read the attribute

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(Pages_Home_Default);
        object[] attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

But this is not practical when you want to do it on the BASE class instead of the DERIVED one.

Can this be done?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I combined the code I have given earlier with a simple line from other sources and here is the code I came up with:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AuthenticationRequired : Attribute
{
    public AuthenticationRequired(bool isMemberRequired)
    {
        Value = isMemberRequired;
    }

    public bool Value { get; private set; }
}


public class Utility
{
    public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(Type classType) where T : Attribute
    {
        object Result = null;

        System.Reflection.MemberInfo Info = classType;

        foreach (var Attr in Info.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        {
            if (Attr.GetType() == typeof(T))
            {
                Result = Attr;
                break;
            }
        }
        return (T)Result;
    }
}

public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthenticationRequired AttrAuth = Utility.GetCustomAttribute<AuthenticationRequired>(this.GetType());

        if (AttrAuth != null && AttrAuth.Value)
        {
            if(!IsMember)
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Membership.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your using MVC, there's an att for that - [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

If your using WebForms then you don't need to use an attribute, you can control this from the web.config using the [authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t%28VS.71%29.aspx) element.

Comment: +1 for the catchy slogan. You better be careful, though, someone might have patented something like it.

Comment: I assume he is using ASP.NET Webforms and that's a MVC attribute.

Comment: Yes. This is MVC and I used similar things on MVC, but my problere here lies with normal regular Asp.NET website, not MVC.

Comment: There is a custom authentication system because of the given requirements. So, I don't think I can use windows's Role management system which is configured in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check it in the attribute itself?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AuthenticationRequired : Attribute
{
    public AuthenticationRequired(bool isMemberRequired)
    {
        if(isMemberRequired && !HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
          FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach is very sound but this class "class AuthenticationRequired" cannot reach the parameter that determines if the client is authenticated. I'd have to check the session and bunch of other things which will result me copying the same methods in this class as weell. I would like to avoid that.